# Angular UI stateparameters does not hold the value of param

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-router

I am designing a asp.net web page with angular at client. In the asp view, I have

```
    <ul tabs-view="LeftPaneView" ><%foreach(var a in JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<WebMenu>>(ViewData.Model.Menus))
                                            {
                                                %>

         <li  ui-sref="demo.leftpane({leftpanevalue:'<%= a.Caption %>'})"><%= a.Caption %></li>

         <% i++;
                                            } %>
                                            } %>
```

And in the app.config I have

```
.state('demo.leftpane', {
      url: '/lpane/?leftpanevalue',
      title: 'left_Pane',
      views: {
        LeftPaneView: {     

          templateUrl: function ($stateParams) { return 'Main.aspx/LeftPane/' + $stateParams.leftpanevalue; }
        }
      }
    })`
```

}

I am expecting the mark up to change based on the leftpanevalue parameter but with in a same state.
The problem now is the request always goes as Main.aspx/LeftPane/Undefined.

Any ideas what i am missing?

Comment: `url: '/lpane/:leftpanevalue'` try using this methodology ..

Comment: Have tried this as well. No change. :(

Comment: I changed the question slightly. i would like to have a single state and render markup based on a different url parameter